# Does MongoDB find() query return documents sorted by creation time?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, database

I need documents sorted by creation time (from oldest to newest).

Since ObjectID saves timestamp by default, we can use it to get documents sorted by creation time with `CollectionName.find().sort({_id: 1})`.

Also, I noticed that regular `CollectionName.find()` query always returns the documents in **same order** as `CollectionName.find().sort({_id: 1})`.

My question is:

Is `CollectionName.find()` guaranteed to return documents in same order as `CollectionName.find().sort({_id: 1})` so I could leave sorting out?

Comment: "always returns the documents in same order" - nah, not always. See my script. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Well, not exactly.
A `db.collection.find()` will give you the documents in the order they appear in the data files most of the times, though this isn't guaranteed.

> **Result Ordering**
>
> Unless you specify the sort() method or use the $near operator, MongoDB does not guarantee the order of query results.

As long as your data files are relatively new and few updates happen, the documents might (and most of the times will) be returned in what appears to be sorted by `_id` since ObjectId is monotonically increasing.

Later in the lifecycle, old documents may have been moved from their old position (because they increased in size and documents are never partitioned) and new ones are written in the place formerly occupied by another document. In this case, a newer document may be returned in a position between two old documents.

There is nothing wrong with sorting documents by `_id`, since the index will be used for that, adding only some latency for document retrieval.

However, I would strongly recommend against using the ObjectId for date operations for several reasons:

1. ObjectIds can not be used for date comparison queries. So you couldn't query for all documents created between date x and date y. To archive that, you'd have to load all documents, extract the date from the ObjectId and compare it – which is extremely inefficient.
2. If the creation date matters, it should be explicitly addressable in the documents
3. I see ObjectIds as a choice of last resort for the `_id` field and tend to use other values (compound on occasions) as `_id`s, since the field is indexed by default and it is very likely that one can save precious RAM by using a more meaningful value as id.

You could use the following for example which utilizes [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/)s

```
{
  _id: {
    creationDate: new ISODate(),
    user: { 
      "$ref" : "creators",
      "$id" : "mwmahlberg",
      "$db" : "users"
    }
  }
}
```

And do a quite cheap sort by using

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id.creationDate:1})
```

Comment: So it's as I thought.

Comment: BTW, this trick you suggested with being able to use the free index on _id to sort on its subfields - it won't work. Indexes on subdocuments are pretty limited. I was skeptical about it from the beginning, but this morning I read the docs and did the test: https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/ad9525bfa2a1d620541e

Comment: @SergioTulentsev wohaa! Have to correct my answer and a few lines of code. Never checked it, really, and it should work for small DBs, but that's a flaw.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, so, are you going to update the answer or what? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Damn, that went past me. On my ever-growing todo... BTW: the gist is deleted, could have been helpful for some people.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: ah, a pity. Guess I was doing spring cleanup and deemed that gist unused. Should have posted it to pastebin or something.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: also, I don't know why I haven't mentioned this 5 years ago, but you absolutely can use object ids to filter by date (provided that ids use the monotonically increasing timestamp-based structure and not fully random 12 bytes like some clients do). In ruby, for example: `BSON::ObjectId.from_time(Time.now) # => BSON::ObjectId('609bacb20000000000000000')`. You can now use this "id" in range queries.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am not quite sure whether this was the case when I wrote the answer. Guess this is going to take a bit longer... ;)

Comment: I'm quite sure it was always possible. Timestamp was the leading part of an objectid at least since ~2010 (which is when I discovered mongo). The drivers may not have had helpers like the above-mentioned `from_time`, but nothing stopped you from just laying bytes out yourself. :)

Answer (score 6):

> Is CollectionName.find() guaranteed to return documents in same order as CollectionName.find().sort({_id: 1})

**No, it's not!** If you didn't specify any order, then a so-called "natural" ordering is used. Meaning that documents will be returned in the order in which they physically appear in data files.

Now, if you only insert documents and never modify them, this natural order will coincide with ascending `_id` order. Imagine, however, that you update a document in such a way that it grows in size and has to be moved to a free slot inside of a data file (usually this means somewhere at the end of the file). If you were to query documents now, they wouldn't follow any sensible (to an external observer) order.

So, if you care about order, make it explicit.

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order

> **natural order**
>
> The order in which the database refers to documents on disk. This is the default sort order. See $natural and Return in Natural Order.

#### Testing script (for the confused)

```
> db.foo.insert({name: 'Joe'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.foo.insert({name: 'Bob'})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55814b944e019172b7d358a0"), "name" : "Joe" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55814ba44e019172b7d358a1"), "name" : "Bob" }

> db.foo.update({_id: ObjectId("55814b944e019172b7d358a0")}, {$set: {answer: "On a sharded collection the $natural operator returns a collection scan sorted in natural order, the order the database inserts and stores documents on disk. Queries that include a sort by $natural order do not use indexes to fulfill the query predicate with the following exception: If the query predicate is an equality condition on the _id field { _id: <value> }, then the query with the sort by $natural order can use the _id index. You cannot specify $natural sort order if the query includes a $text expression."}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55814ba44e019172b7d358a1"), "name" : "Bob" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55814b944e019172b7d358a0"), "name" : "Joe", "answer" : "On a sharded collection the $natural operator returns a collection scan sorted in natural order, the order the database inserts and stores documents on disk. Queries that include a sort by $natural order do not use indexes to fulfill the query predicate with the following exception: If the query predicate is an equality condition on the _id field { _id: <value> }, then the query with the sort by $natural order can use the _id index. You cannot specify $natural sort order if the query includes a $text expression." }
```

Comment: "Natural" order can only be achieved by using `.sort({ "$natural': 1 })` which is the only way to ask for data "in the order it is stored on disk". Also since "data on disk" can "move" ( and regularly does ) that is not the "insertion order".

Comment: Read closely, this answer doesn't claim that natural order is the same as insertion order. In fact, this whole answer is about how it's not the same.

Comment: Quote: *"If you didn't specify any order, then a so-called "natural" ordering is used"*. Your words not mine. That is not true

Comment: Yes, natural order, not insertion order.

Comment: This test is invalid. A sharded collection uses the "shard key" for selection and possible "scatter gather".  So the primary key is not used here. None of this backs up `$natural` since if you actually showed a document growing between different queries then the order shown by `$natural` would be changed between results since the document on disk has moved.

Comment: Sharded collection? Who said anything about sharded collection?

Comment: "the order shown by $natural would be changed between results since the document on disk has moved" - my point exactly.

Comment: Until a document migration happens, natural order is identical to a sort on ObjectId, which is monotonically increasing. However, even then, querying without a sort modifier may return the documents in arbitrary order, as stated in the documentation. Giving the sort order of `natural` guarantees the documents to be returned in order they appear on disk.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: documentation clearly states that natural is the default sort order, though. And it corresponds well with my experience. If we do slave reading, then obviously, we may get different results if identical queries hit different slaves, but still it'd be natural ordering for each slave.

Comment: BTW, I can't imagine why would anyone specifically request natural ordering (except for capped collections, perhaps).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the quote in my answer is life from the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#result-ordering

Comment: And you would want to specify the natural order on spinning disks to reduce latency overhead.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg yeah, we got two pieces of documentation contradict one another. But in either case, it's most definitely not an implicit sort on `{_id: 1}` :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that's where I wholeheartedly agree with you. However, explicitly specifying natural sort has its use cases - imho basically every query where you don't care for the order at all and you *know* you are on spinning disks and you know that the docs are not in your working set (seldomly executed regex searches over unindexed fields come to my mind), though that should be tested for every use case, of course.